# Purpose of ToCharacterCode

Tags: string-manipulation, character-encoding

Is `ToCharacterCode` function the same as assigning ASCII decimal to a character?

Comment: If you doubt the third bullet point under the "Details" section of the doc page for `ToCharacterCode[]`, you can always do a comparison with a table like the one in [this page](https://www.ascii-code.com) to see for yourself.

Comment: The purpose and uses for that function are rather well defined in [its documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToCharacterCode.html). Have you tried running a few examples to see if your expectation of its functionality is correct? Which specific part of the docs, or which specific behavior is unclear?

Comment: For characters on an American English keyboard: yes.  For other languages read: "ToCharacterCode" from the help."

Comment: Yes I have tested it out on a string and it matched but I couldn't see a mention of ASCII in "ToCharacterCode" help section so didn't want to be caught out by making a false assumption. I have since seen it mentions ASCII "standard" if I open up the details section instead of scrolling down

Comment: "there was no mention of ASCII in `ToCharacterCode` help section" - as previously noted, please read the "Details" section of the page; a lot is explained there. If anything there is unclear, please edit your question to mention what you are having trouble with.

Comment: I assume ASCII standard means ASCII decimal

Comment: Indeed, it is decimal; hex would need to be entered with syntax like `16^^DEADBEEF`, for instance.

Comment: I find "ASCII" occurs five times on the help page (in all sections including once in "Details"), if I use the search feature (<kbd>cmd</kbd>-f on my Mac). -- All integers are displayed in decimal by default; but they are of type `Integer` and the display format does not affect their value.

Answer (score 3):

The result is not decimal: it's a `List` of `Integer`s that by default displays as decimal in `{}`.

The encodings are mostly *Unicode*, which has the same numbering as ASCII for characters in ASCII, but includes many more characters:

```
ToCharacterCode["Aあ"]
(* {65, 12354} *)
```

There are some exceptions for backward compatibility, reflecting the fact that *Mathematica* is older than Unicode.